# how to setup openstack dynamic resource allocation and live migration using dashboard?

Tags: resources, openstack, data-migration

sorry to ask my questions on stackoverflow instead of ask.openstack. I really need answers and ask.openstack is useless. my questions are:

1. what is openstack heat?
2. how to setup dynamic resource allocation for an instance using dashboard?
3. is there any way to automatically live migrate instances on openstack when dynamic resource allocation is active and openstack node runs out of resources?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer-1:**

***OpenStack Heat:***

> Heat is a service to orchestrate composite cloud applications using a
>   declarative template format through an OpenStack-native REST API.

Heat is a project under **OpenStack** tent which is used for orchestration of resources using templates in yaml format

1. Heat template is defined with sections like `definition`, `parameters`, `resources`, `outputs`
2. Based on the topology and requirement of resources like `VM`, `port`, `network`, `subnet` ... the resources are defined in template. All the supported resource types are available at **https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/template_guide/openstack.html**

Official documentation of heat: **https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/**

**Answer-2:**

**Dynamic resource allocation for instance using dashboard**

`Dynamic resource allocation` is allocating/changing the resources after instance is up and running, for example `attach the port to instance`, `attach volume to instance`, `resize the instance`... . Yes these can be done from dashboard/horizon.

**Answer-3:**

**Live-migration of instance:**

Yes, live migration can be done and step by step procedure available at **https://docs.openstack.org/nova/pike/admin/live-migration-usage.html**